# How to get user created schemas in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to list all the schemas that have been created by user. How do I do it?
This script

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.schemas
WHERE schema_id < 16000
```

returns dbo, sys but I don't need them.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.schemas
WHERE schema_id <= 16383 AND name NOT IN ('dbo', 'sys')
```

You could assume that dbo etc are the lowest few numbers. This works on my SQL Server 2005 box

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.schemas
WHERE schema_id BETWEEN 5 AND 16383
```

My schemas are numbers 5 to 13 for example.

Comment: This seems to work. Is it for sure that for any database user created schemas have schema_id between 5 and 16383?

Comment: @StuffHappens: for my SQL Server 2005, yes

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA where SCHEMA_OWNER = 'dbo' and schema_name <> 'dbo'
```

Comment: the result contains dbo as well